# Huge memory leak during Hibernate entity persisting, why?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, memory-leaks, persistence

I am using Hibernate with JPA EntityManager, not Hibernate sessions. Most people seem to recommend using a new EntityManager for every transaction, so that is what I'm doing.

So, I create 10000 new entities in a row. The heap usage is about 90 MB on the first iteration and 5 GB on the last one.

[image: java memory leak]

This is my iteration code:

```java
    Session session = Core.getDatabase().createEntityManager().unwrap(Session.class);
    Query query = session.getNamedQuery("Account.getAllIds");
    query.setReadOnly(true);
    query.setFetchSize(100);
    ScrollableResults accounts = query.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);

    EntityManager entityManager = Core.getDatabase().createEntityManager();
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

    while (accounts.next()) {

        int id = (int) accounts.get(0);
        Account account = entityManager.getReference(Account.class, id);

        Core.getDatabase().persist(new AccountTest(account));
        changes++;

    }

    entityManager.close();
    accounts.close();
    session.close();
```

And my persistence function:

```java
public class Database
{
    private final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    public Database(String host, String database, String user, String password)
    {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":3306/" + database);
        properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", user);
        properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", password);

        entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("default", properties);
    }

    public EntityManager createEntityManager()
    {
        return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

    public void persist(Object... objects)
    {
        EntityManager entityManager = createEntityManager();
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

        for (Object object : objects) {
            entityManager.persist(object);
        }

        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        entityManager.clear();
        entityManager.close();
    }
}
```

So I iterate over all account entities (10k, but using Hibernate Session because of the scrolling functionality) and want to create a new AccountTest for every account.

Comment: That's not a memory leak, that's the called the session cache. You need to understand how JPA works.

Comment: Is em.clear(); em.close(); em.finalize(); not already clearing its cache? What  would I have to call instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you hold the first `EntityManager` opened the whole time, while only clearing and closing another `EntityManager` that's only used for persisting one item.

At the end, you have all the Account entities loaded in the first `EntityManager`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I use the first EM for calling getReference for every account ID. Should I create a new EM for every getReference call or could I even replace the getReference call with "a = new Account(); a.setId(id)" since I can be totally sure that ID exists in database?

Comment: If you are sure the `Account` exists in the DB, than Hibernate allows you to reference entities using transient entities that have their id set. This feature is Hibernate specific, it's not a JPA standard.